# Line-Height on a li element

Tags: html, css

I have some bullets on my page and I am trying to reduce the line height when the bullet spans 2 or more lines.

[What my list currently looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDrYT.png)

I have tried

```
li { 
     line-height: 20px;
 }
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Please show a complete example.

Comment: Try use line-height: 20px !important; Maybe you are using a css framework that overrides your css?

Comment: Pls add more details. To prevent overriding styles by browser or some libraries better define class for your `<li> `.my-list` for example.  Using `!important` is bad practice you should avoid that when possible.

Answer (score 0):

`line-height` on list items works. Maybe your `font-size` is 20px; so you don't see any difference? Try `line-height: 20px !important;` maybe you are using a css framework that overrides your css.

```css
ul li {
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Line height should work just fine on li elements. I would also try margins if that does not work:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbmrRJ

```
ul > li {
 line-height: 60px;
}
ol > li {
  margin: 60px 0px;
}

<ul>
  <li>a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>b</li>
</ul>
<ol>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ol>
```

It may be that you are not selecting the right class. Try right-clicking your

item, inspecting the element on the browser and checking if the line height has been applied. If it is not applied, the line-height property would have a line going through it, in which case, you will have to use a different selector. 
w3schools has a good reference to selectors:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Hope that helps!

Comment: What are <or> tags? you meant <ol> or <ul>?

Comment: It's better to use padding so you stay inside the list item like line-height do. padding: 10px 0; But keep in mind that  if your list items has multiple lines it's not the same as a line-height.